# Python: What is the fastest way to split and join these strings?

Tags: python, split, concatenation

I have a script where a global constant ZETA is input by a user

ZETA = alpha.*

A user will supply an input like:

```
alpha.aaa_xxx
alpha.bbb_yyy
alpha.abc_xyz
etc...
```

The alpha.* arguments are representative of integers and there are so many of them that building a class function to assign outputs to every known integer value would be messy.

Later in my code from the input given to ZETA I need outputs that look like this:

```
beta.aaa, beta.xxx
beta.bbb, beta.yyy
beta.abc, beta.xyz
```

I'd like to use a list, split, and join method to get these outputs, but I've been running into an error:

when I try to list(ZETA), I was hoping for:

```
a, l, p, h, a, ., a, a, a, _, x, x, x
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I understand why... but it throws a kink in my plan for sure.  Thoughts?

Thanks!

ETA:

so I think I can get to where I need to be if I require the inputs to be in quotes:

'alpha.aaa_xxx'

instead of

alpha.aaa_xxx

is there any way around that?

Comment: Posting code is almost essential to getting assistance in fixing it.

Comment: Look into the difference between `raw_input` and `input`. Once again, we really need to see the code to help.

Comment: It sounds like you are using `input()` to ask for this value, which immediately forgets about the _name_ of the variable the user typed and only stores the _result_ of the entered expression. Instead, get the name first by using `raw_input()` and then call `eval()` to extract the value (in fact, `input()` is pretty much `eval(raw_input())`.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's say you have your data in one list.

```
sample = ['alpha.111_222', 'alpha.222_444', 'alpha.433_cvx'] # for example
```

You can read your file into list, but, beauty of generators, you don't have to, you can easily build one generator yourself for read file.

As far as I understood you want to cut out alpha part (split by .) first.
We can do this by generator

```
[y.split('.') for y in sample] # list of [['alpha', 'xxx_yyy'], ...]
```

Now we want get second member of each list and split it by '_'. Same idea with generator.

```
[x.split('_') for x in [y.split('.')[1] for y in sample]]
```

Now, when we have list of pairs ['xxx', 'yyy'] all we need is form new lines like this

```
result = ["beta.%s, beta.%s" % (x[0],x[1]) for x in [x.split('_') for x in [y.split('.')[1] for y in sample]]] # ['beta.xxx, beta.yyy', ...]
```

Or, if you dislike nested generators, you can write code like this:

```
k = [x.split('.')[1] for x in sample]
l = [x.split('_') for x in k]
result = ["beta.%s, beta.%s" % (x[0],x[1]) for x in l]
```

Looks a bit clearer, more variables though. Now, all we need is print. Or output to file.

```
for item in result:
    print item
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys!

I thought I'd share my final solution as implemented in our sand-boxed environment.  All of this allows for a changing many lines of code in a currency trading script with only a single change to user input.   I'm able to access a myriad of data about a new currency pair without having to change every reference to the new pair, portfolio balances, starting balances, log outputs, etc. throughout hundreds of lines of code.

```
PAIR        = 'btc_usd'  # requires format 'xxx_yyy'

def instruments(pair):

    currency_code   = PAIR.split('_')[1]
    asset_code      = PAIR.split('_')[0]  
    instrument_pair = asset_code + '_' + currency_code
    instrument      = pairs[instrument_pair]
    currency        = portfolio[currencies[currency_code]]
    assets          = portfolio[currencies[asset_code]]
    currency_CODE   = (currency_code).upper()
    asset_CODE      = (asset_code).upper()
    if info.tick == 0:
        storage.initial_currency = currency
        storage.initial_assets = assets

    return (instrument_pair, instrument, currency_CODE, currency_code, currency, 
        storage.initial_currency, asset_CODE, asset_code, assets, storage.initial_assets)

def tick():

    (instrument_pair, instrument, currency_CODE, currency_code, currency, storage.initial_currency, 
        asset_CODE, asset_code, assets, storage.initial_assets) = instruments(PAIR)

    if info.tick == 0:
        buy(instrument, 1)
    if info.tick == 1:
        log('******************************')        
        log('User Input......: %s' % PAIR)
        log('instrument pair.: %s' % instrument_pair)
        log('instrument......: %s' % instrument)
        log('CURRENCY CODE...: %s' % currency_CODE)        
        log('currency code...: %s' % currency_code)
        log('currency........: %.2f' % currency)
        log('initial currency: %.2f' % storage.initial_currency)
        log('ASSET CODE......: %s' % asset_CODE)          
        log('asset code......: %s' % asset_code) 
        log('assets..........: %.2f' % assets)
        log('initial assets..: %.2f' % storage.initial_assets)
        log('******************************')
```

Which in our sandbox yields:

```
[2014-06-09 02:00:00]  BUY: 1.00 BTC (at 648.00 USD)
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] ******************************
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] User Input......: btc_usd
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] instrument pair.: btc_usd
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] instrument......: 2000
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] CURRENCY CODE...: USD
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] currency code...: usd
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] currency........: 352.00
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] initial currency: 1000.00
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] ASSET CODE......: BTC
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] asset code......: btc
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] assets..........: 1.00
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] initial assets..: 0.00
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] ******************************
```

An alternative solution I also arrived at was:

```
PAIR        = 'Btc#@#$^@% _uSd'  # will also work with input 'BTCUSD'

def instruments(pair):

    p = filter(str.isalpha, pair).lower()
    currency_code   = ''.join(list((p)[3:6]))
    asset_code      = ''.join(list((p)[0:3]))      
    instrument_pair = asset_code + '_' + currency_code
    instrument      = pairs[instrument_pair]
    currency        = portfolio[currencies[currency_code]]
    assets          = portfolio[currencies[asset_code]]
    currency_CODE   = (currency_code).upper()
    asset_CODE      = (asset_code).upper()
    if info.tick == 0:
        storage.initial_currency = currency
        storage.initial_assets = assets

    return (instrument_pair, instrument, currency_CODE, currency_code, currency, 
        storage.initial_currency, asset_CODE, asset_code, assets, storage.initial_assets)

def tick():

    (instrument_pair, instrument, currency_CODE, currency_code, currency, storage.initial_currency, 
        asset_CODE, asset_code, assets, storage.initial_assets) = instruments(PAIR)

    if info.tick == 0:
        buy(instrument, 1)
    if info.tick == 1:
        log('******************************')        
        log('User Input......: %s' % PAIR)
        log('instrument pair.: %s' % instrument_pair)
        log('instrument......: %s' % instrument)
        log('CURRENCY CODE...: %s' % currency_CODE)        
        log('currency code...: %s' % currency_code)
        log('currency........: %.2f' % currency)
        log('initial currency: %.2f' % storage.initial_currency)
        log('ASSET CODE......: %s' % asset_CODE)          
        log('asset code......: %s' % asset_code) 
        log('assets..........: %.2f' % assets)
        log('initial assets..: %.2f' % storage.initial_assets)
        log('******************************')
```

which yeilds:

```
[2014-06-09 02:00:00]  BUY: 1.00 BTC (at 648.00 USD)
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] ******************************
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] User Input......: Btc#@#$^@% _uSd
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] instrument pair.: btc_usd
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] instrument......: 2000
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] CURRENCY CODE...: USD
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] currency code...: usd
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] currency........: 352.00
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] initial currency: 1000.00
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] ASSET CODE......: BTC
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] asset code......: btc
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] assets..........: 1.00
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] initial assets..: 0.00
[2014-06-09 02:15:00] ******************************
```